# Adding box shadow to all sides in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

So, I am having a QWidget and a dummy text. So, I want the label to be quite raised. So, I choose QGraphicsDropShadowEffect and added as an graphic effect. But, I can only see the box shadow on only two sides, bottom and right. I want to add shadow to other two sides as well

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, Qt


def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    widget = QWidget()

    textLabel = QLabel(widget)

    textLabel.setText("Hello World!")

    textLabel.setStyleSheet(
        "background-color: #4C566A; color: #88C0D0; font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold"
    )

    textLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter | Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)

    textLabel.setGeometry(QRect(100, 100, 500, 500))

    effect = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect()

    effect.setBlurRadius(15)

    textLabel.setGraphicsEffect(effect)

    textLabel.move(110, 85)

    widget.setGeometry(50, 50, 320, 200)

    widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #2E3440")

    widget.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 Example")

    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window()
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation about QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, specifically the [`offset`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsdropshadoweffect.html#offset-prop) property? Use `effect.setOffset(0, 0)`.

Comment: [Here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/77576/painting-shadow-around-a-parentless-qwidget/12) is a solution, which might comes close to your idea. It is written in __Qt__ for __C++__, maybe you would like to _translate_ it? Others with the same issue will surely be thankful.

Comment: @angelogro please read the question more carefully: the OP is already getting the shadow, the problem is that the offset wasn't set to the center.

Comment: @musicamante What is OP? I was aware that the program already produced a shadow. However I thought a shadow to all directions was required. The accepted answer does not produce **any** shadow... Apparently I totally missed the point.

Comment: @angelogro OP stands for "Original Post[er]", refers to the question or who posted it. An "all directions" shadow is exactly what `setOffset(0, 0)` does, you probably don't see it because of the small blur radius and the fact that the used colors have a very low contrast. The post you linked refers to the creation of a shadow for the *top level* widget, which is a different thing than what's being asked here (a shadow for a *child* widget, the label, shown on the parent area).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @musicamante said, you should set the offset to (0 , 0)

Here is the complete answer:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, Qt


def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    widget = QWidget()

    textLabel = QLabel(widget)

    textLabel.setText("Hello World!")

    textLabel.setStyleSheet(
        "background-color: #4C566A; color: #88C0D0; font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold"
    )

    textLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter | Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)

    textLabel.setGeometry(QRect(100, 100, 500, 500))

    effect = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect()

    effect.setOffset(0, 0)

    effect.setBlurRadius(15)

    textLabel.setGraphicsEffect(effect)

    textLabel.move(110, 85)

    widget.setGeometry(50, 50, 320, 200)

    widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: #2E3440")

    widget.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 Example")

    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    window()
```